# When I create a dynamic array with a custom type, even with strings, it doesn't seem to work

Tags: c++, arrays, templates

I am training to code an harder project that requires the implementation of a Binary search tree.
My work made me focus on custom types and templates.
Now my idea was to create a custom type array that is templated to accept any type of elements.
I even included an iterator, just to check how it worked.
Then I created a custom class called MyPairs(since the BST accepts pairs {key,value}).
The fact is that when I try to implement an array of such type I get errors like std::bad_array_new_lenght
or std::bad_alloc.
I am sure that it all is caused by the dinamic array initialization, but I can't figure out what is the problem.   Sometimes the code doesn't work even for type int. What I am doing wrong? 
I report the code I made. You can find more comments on what I have tried to do.

```
template<typename T>
class array{     //third custom type, a regular array that is created in the heap

T* start;
std::size_t size;
const int dimension = 10;//i decided, to simplify things to fix the array dimension

public:
array()
:start{new T[dimension]}, size{0} {}////////////////HERE SEEMS TO BE THE PROBLEM



~array()
{
std::cout<<"Destructor Called"<<std::endl;
delete[] start;
}


MyIterator<T> insert(T item){
if (size == dimension-1)
    throw TooFullException{"Array is too small"};
start[size] = item;
MyIterator<T> x{start+size};
++size;
std::cout<<"size:"<<size<<std::endl;
return x;
}

MyIterator<T> begin(){
MyIterator<T> x{start};
return x;
}

MyIterator<T> end(){
MyIterator<T> x{start+size};
return x;
}


friend
std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, array& x)//printing the array
{
for(MyIterator<T> i = x.begin(); i != x.end(); ++i)
    os<<*i<<" ";
os<<std::endl;
return os;
}
```

EDIT: I restricted the code so now you can see where the error is

Comment: I'm assuming you can't use std::vector?

Comment: I suggest to minimize your code to include the place where your problem occurs only. this will enable one trying to help you to do that easily.

Comment: You should replace dynamic memory allocation with STL containers or smart pointers to avoid such problems. You won't pass a code review if you use dynamic memory allocation and it's not necessary.

Comment: Your container violates [the rule of three](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/rule_of_three).

Comment: I did not know this rule, it is very relevant

Answer (score 0):

I found someone answered my question.Since they deleted the post(I don't know why since it was correct and helpful) I will report it here.
In the end I just had to reorder the elements of the class List, according to the initialization order.

```
class array{     

const int dimension = 10;//i decided, to simplify things to fix the array dimension
T* start;
std::size_t size;

public:
array()
:start{new T[dimension]}, size{0} {}//Now this works
 ...
```

Now it works! Thanks to the one who posted the answer first